# TCPClient and TCPListener only listening not sending

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, synchronous, tcplistener

Hi I am currently in the process of making two programs, one of the is designed to act as a server and one of them is designed to act as a client. 
I am currently having an issue, where the server can receive messages from the client but is unable to send them back.

The client and server send message code is identical

```
    public void SendMessage(MessageContainer msg)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IP,Port);
        serializer.Serialize(client.GetStream(), msg);
        client.Close();
    }
```

The only difference in the programs is the listener as the server runs 24/7, same for the client but, the client can expect a specific message to occur after sending one, such as a RSA Key Request.
The server and client have the same GetMessage Routine

```
    public MessageContainer GetMessage()
    {
        if (listener.Pending())
        {
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            string IP = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            MessageContainer container = (MessageContainer)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
            container.IP = IP;
            return container;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But for listening the client also has the specific message method, which does not seem to be working in any scenario.

```
    public MessageContainer GetSpecificMessage(string Expectation)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        MessageContainer msg = null;
        do
        {
            msg = GetMessage();
            if (msg != null)
            {
                if (msg.Message == Expectation)
                {
                    timer.Start();
                    return msg;
                }
                else
                {
                    messages.Enqueue(msg);
                    msg = null;
                }
            }
        }
        while (msg == null);
        return null;
    }
```

I've been attempting to work on this problem for a while, including re-coding my entire server but I always result in the same error, I've tried disabling Mcafee firewalls on both machines and there was still no progress with the issue.
Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: The server doesn't send to the client by creating a new TcpClient

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs to accept the client socket, also called a child socket and then send back top the child socket.

On the server your SendMessage would become:

```
public void SendMessage(MessageContainer msg, TcpClient client)
{
    serializer.Serialize(client.GetStream(), msg);
}
```

Where client is the value you get here:

```
TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

You then use that client that came from Listening/Accepting for bi directional communications.

You also don't need to close the TcpClient until all your messages are finished and your completely done with the sockets.

So on the server you listen for Tcp Connections using `AcceptTcpClient` each connection gets a TcpClient of it's own which is sometimes called a `child client`, but it's just a normal socket that you can read and write from.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I tried using your approach just now, but I’m still encountering the same problem, the only issue is that the client is still not receiving the message, but with your suggestion all that’s happened is the error has been cancelled. Is the problem on the listener side then, but I left the listener active.